# Get a list of running tasks in application tab of task manager

Tags: c++, windows, taskmanager

Is there a way to get a list of all the running applications only in windows. By application i mean the tasks shown in the application tab of task manager. [As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xX90.png)

Just some background information, one part of my program shows (a bit like task manager) all the currently running application. So in essence it can be thought of like ways to export the list of tasks from the applications tab.

I am aware using tasklist to get a list of all processes and you can apply filters to it but I am unsure which combination of filters would give the desired output.

EDIT - I have so far managed to apply a filter and output the filtered list to a desired location. Now i am stuck because I do not know what qualifies as a application in task manager so i am not sure which combination of filter i need to apply.

Tasklist is a CMD command so my aim is to, if possible filter out the tasks which do not fall into the applications tab, export the list as a CSV file and create a piece of code which reads off the csv and displays the data in c++ (for first prototype).

Comment: The answer to "Is it possible to do...?" is usually "yes" (and in rare cases "no"). Imho the question could be improved substantially if you would show what you tried, explained how it does not work, and ask how to fix it

Comment: What have you already tried, just putting a basic search into Google for for "Windows Task Manager Code" returns 10 of hits?

Comment: I have edited the original post

Comment: And @RichardCritten if i could find answer in google i wouldn't be asking it would i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this in the future i found a solution using VBS.

```
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim fso
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set f = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\........\Documents\output.csv", 2)
Set Tasks = Word.Tasks
For Each Task in Tasks
   If Task.Visible Then f.Writeline Task.Name
Next
Word.Quit
```

This detects all current 'applications' and outputs the list to a csv file.